# How can I run a query passing information from a form?

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I guess this is a silly question, but I'm having problems figuring this out.

I have two tables with loads of information used to make reports.

I have a query that joins these two tables.

The same query adds two simple filters: A date range and an ID checker.

The reports are supposed to be printed withing a date range with a specific ID.

Every time I need to change the query data range I need to manually edit it and change the parameters.

How can I make a form and pass this information to the query so I won't have to manually update the query every week?

I made a new form with two date fields and I would need some code to pass this information to the query before opening it, but [`DoCmd.OpenQuery Method`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb238028%28v=office.12%29.aspx) doesn't permit I pass any information.

Ideally I'd prefer to use a SQL command to set the query and then open it, is this even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, I am using this method often:
Declare variables in a Module and write a function for each one that simply returns the value. You can then use the function call within the Query-Designer (e. g. criteria = `Between getMyValue1() AND getMyValue2()`)
You can then set the global variables before opening the query.
(This has worked better for me than Query-Parameters or direct references to form fields within queries.)

Comment: Honestly, I'm not sure if this was the most elegant way to solve my problem but I really loved the fact that I can use functions within queries, this makes so many things so much easier - and I realized that I can actually call SQL commands using functions. Anyways, this solved my problems and blew my mind.

Comment: I have to agree that this is a really nice idea and an elegant solution!

Comment: I would even agree that this is _not_ really elegant on first sight, but to my mind the QueryDefs.Parameters should really be there just for this, but they don't work (I know only that they work when you set them and then directly work with QueryDef.OpenRecordSet inside vba code.) So I'm used to going this way now...

Answer (score 1):

Open the report with a filter:

```
Dim sWhere as String
sWhere = "Tbl_Swift.Data >= #10/01/2012# AND Tbl_Swift.Data <= #10/10/2012#"
DoCmd.OpenReport "rptMyReportName", acViewPreview, ,sWhere
```

(I'm not sure if "BETWEEN" will work or not, although I think it should if you'd write it properly.)

Comment: It can't be this easy... I'm trying this now.

Comment: And it wasn't. I tried using the filter ´"Tbl_Swift.Data = "Tbl_Swift.Data = Between #01/01/2012# And #10/10/2012#"´ and I get a runtime 3075 error.

Comment: So you're saying you have a field named Data that holds date information? I'd recommend naming your fields more appropriately.

Comment: @JohnnyBigoode Try this: `sWhere = "Tbl_Swift.Data Between #2012-01-01# AND #2012-10-10#"`

Comment: +1 Use your form to collect the date range values, then create your OpenReport WhereCondition parameter (sWhere) string based on those dates.

Answer (score 1):

You could also put a condition in your query that refers to a field in your form:

```
SELECT ... WHERE ID = [Forms]![FormName]![TextField]
```

Comment: Will this alter the code of the query? Should I run the SQL command and then simply DoCmd.OpenQuery?

Comment: You have to alter the code of the query just once, then you can just call DoCmd.OpenQuery. You don't have to use a query with parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options.

1. Do not put values of parameters in the query. Access will always ask for these values on every execution of query.
2. use DATE() function to get the current date and calculate the week start and end accordingly. This way, you will never have to provide the date.

Comment: Ok... But I don't want to manually type the values, I want Access to grab the information typed on the form.